# why does the irqaction structure in linux kernel refer to a list of interrupt handlers

Tags: linux

I was trying to understand the linux interrupt handling mechanism. But I am currently stuck up at a very basic query - why is the 'irqaction' structure pointing to a list of interrupt handlers ? Isnt the do_IRQ function invoked for an interrupt from a particular source(device). Then shouldnt the interrupt handler as registered by that device be invoked?

Comment: What do you mean that struct irqaction is pointing to a list of interrupt handlers ?

Comment: the irqaction structure has a pointer 'next' that points to the next irqaction structure. And the irqaction structure has a 'handler' that is invoked for all the irqactions in this linked list. So when an interrupt occurs, the do_IRQ function is called which ultimately traverses this whole list and calls the handlers. What I want to know is why for a particular IRQ we have to execute a list of handlers.

Comment: As the comments for that struct says, that's only for shared interrupts - i.e. when several devices share the same irq line.

Comment: But then where is it checked which of the devices sharing the interrupts raised the current interrupt.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47306/how-does-the-linux-kernel-handle-shared-irqs might point you to something. Note that the ->next pointer is only used for shared interrupts, and your device driver needs to explicitly request that it supports a shared IRQ.

Comment: yes the device driver would have placed a request for a shared IRQ. But what I am still not clear is that when ultimately an IRQ is received and while we are traversing this list and invoking the various handlers of the devices sharing the IRQ, then isnt it required to know which device actually generated that interrupt. Maybe my question is a bit silly and I might be missing out something very basic.But the query is really troubling me.

Comment: Yes, you need some device specific way to know if your device was the one generating an interrupt, e.g. you read a status register that can tell you whether an interrupt is pending - if it isn't, your irq handler should return and otherwise do nothing. If your hardware has no capability to query information on whether it generated an interrupt, you cannot install a shared irq handler for it either. There's code snippets in the 2. answer in the link I aded above.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I really wanted to know